# Cloud service to upload files from java app

Tags: java, cloud, google-cloud-storage

I want a filesystem in the cloud to upload and download files with a java library.
I know Google Cloud Service has the service but i need one that have free storage until 2 ou 3 Gb.

Tks

Comment: Google Cloud Storage has a free 5 GB quota.

Comment: By i need to put a credit card number and i dont want it

Comment: Actually you don't. You get a free 5 GB for any new app you create, even if you don't put your credit card.

Answer (score 1):

For Google-specific solutions, [Google Drive](https://www.google.com/drive/) supports [15GB of free storage](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375123?hl=en) and supports Java (see their [Java Example Drive App](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/examples/java) or [Android Demos](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos)). Also, [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) supports a free trial, but otherwise charges per the [price sheet](https://cloud.google.com/storage/#pricing), and also offers Java support through the [Cloud Storage API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/storage/v1) or third party toolkits, such as [JetS3t](http://www.jets3t.org/).

There are also many non-Google cloud storage products, many of which have a free tier.

Comment: Hello, please vote positive my question. if you dont do it i need to remove the question because this removes-me points